# use a single array to implement three stacks

Tags: java, algorithm

Debugging on some solutions for this problem, and for the following code snippet, I think the logic is wrong in method pop(), since when executing "indexUsed--", spaces are removed continuously, but when deleting elements, it is not necessarily to be continuous.

Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

```
int stackSize = 300;
int indexUsed = 0;
int[] stackPointer = { -1, -1, -1 };
StackNode[] buffer = new StackNode[stackSize * 3];
void push(int stackNum, int value) {
    int lastIndex = stackPointer[stackNum];
    stackPointer[stackNum] = indexUsed;
    indexUsed++;
    buffer[stackPointer[stackNum]] = new StackNode(lastIndex, value);
}
int pop(int stackNum) {
    int value = buffer[stackPointer[stackNum]].value;
    int lastIndex = stackPointer[stackNum];
    stackPointer[stackNum] = buffer[stackPointer[stackNum]].previous;
    buffer[lastIndex] = null;
    indexUsed--;
    return value;
}
int peek(int stack) { return buffer[stackPointer[stack]].value; }
boolean isEmpty(int stackNum) { return stackPointer[stackNum] == -1; }

class StackNode {
    public int previous;
    public int value;
    public StackNode(int p, int v) {
        value = v;
        previous = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what goes wrong? I've test your code and seems fine.

Comment: I don't get the idea: how would using `buffer` be better than just using three non-related linked lists, anyway?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller if insert sequence stack 1, stack 2 and stack 3, and remove stack 1, since elements are allocated continuously, not sure if elements in stack 3 is removed.

Comment: @greybeard this is what the problem is asking. :)

Comment: @LinMa the right behavior is that all three stacks must be completely separated, right? Please, show some situation that you think can give some wrong behavior.

Comment: @JohnnyWiller thanks, but in code, it does not restrict stacks to be continuous, correct?

Comment: @LinMa what you mean with continuous?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller, I mean elements of each stack have to be sit together? If I have the wrong understanding, please feel free to correct me what do you mean "must be completely separated"?

Comment: @LinMa this implementation is right, I will post an answer to you, but I'm a bit confused what really you want to know. `" since when executing "indexUsed--", spaces are removed continuously"`, I didn't get what is the problem with decreasing indexUsed, that number is necessary to points to the top of the buffer

Comment: @JohnnyWiller, I may have wrong understanding. Looking forward to your answer and will mark it as answered. :))

Comment: @JohnnyWiller, answer is appreciated. Looking forward to. :)

Comment: @LinMa yeah, i will. Wait a couple minutes

Comment: @LinMa So, i'm sorry, my answer was wrong. I guess you already have solved you doubt.

Comment: Thanks all the same Johnny! Have a good day. :)

Comment: This is a nice question!

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, enjoy the discussion with you and vote up for your reply and comments. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, this approach is not only ridiculously inefficient and overcomplicated, but also **incorrect**.

Here is the simple test to prove:

```
    StackArray stack = new StackArray();
    stack.push(0, 0);
    stack.push(1, 10);
    System.out.println(stack.pop(0));
    stack.push(1, 20);
    System.out.println(stack.pop(1));
    System.out.println(stack.pop(1));
```

Produces:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at StackArray.pop(StackArray.java:18)
```

Stack data structure is usually implemented as array or single-linked list. Linked list is less efficient, because its elements are scattered across the heap, also its elements have memory overhead (node object with pointers). Array, on the other hand, is faster, but it has fixed size, so it can't be used for all tasks.

Each of these approaches has its pros and cons, but there is absolutely no point in creating mixed approach that has **only disadvantages** of both approaches (has fixed capacity and memory overhead).

---

If this is a synthetic task with the restriction of using only one array to store elements of all three stacks, then following approach can be used.

Logically split elements of array in pairs. Each pair will represent one node of single-linked list. First element of the pair will hold the value, while second element will be the pointer to the next node.

It's clear that array can hold any number of independent single-linked lists (as long as it has sufficient capacity) and you know the indices of the heads.

The idea is similar to the approach given in description, to hold the pointers to the heads of three lists, but (!) in addition hold the pointer to the list that represent "free memory" and includes all non-occupied elements of the array. Initially this "heap" list will contain all elements of the array. When you `push` element into one of the stacks, you need to `pop` element from the `heap` and use it to create element of the desired stack. When element is `popped` from the stack, this element is `pushed` back to heap.

Comment: Thanks Aivean, wondering if we want to use linked list to manage 3 stacks, how do you suggest to fix this problem? :)

Comment: @LinMa if you have **three stacks**, it's reasonable to represent them as **three separate stacks**. Java has standard interface [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) that represents stacks. Select from it's implementations, `ArrayDeque` or `LinkedList`. Prefer former if you know stack size in advance.

Comment: Thanks Aivean, fully understand. This question is a bit tricky, which has the restriction of only one array. Any thoughts how to use one array for 3 stacks? :)

Comment: @LinMa I think you need to create separate question and provide all necessary details and restrictions on your task. Because right now `Deque[]` is the answer (only one array of stacks).

Comment: @LinMa I updated my answer with the possible solution to your problem (in case it is not a real-world problem but rather synthetic puzzle)

Comment: Thanks Aivean, I think the issue of original solution is, it does not put the element back to the buffer when pop from a stack?

Comment: @LinMa, not exactly. Your original description of the issue is accurate. The fix will be to create another "stack" (similar to stacks 0..2) that will store the indices of free elements of the buffer. You need to pop that stack to get analogue of `indexUsed` (only it will not be consequent). Also, when removing elements from "regular stacks", you need to release their indices (put them back to "free indices" stack).

Comment: Thanks Aivean, cannot use an array (for array I mean continuous memory space)? I think for the "another stack", you mean the memory space is not continuous, correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can start one of the stacks from one end of the array. You can start the other stack from the other end of the array. You can put the third stack in the middle. When, one of the side stacks need space, you need to shift the middle stack. However, I have another implementation by help of free list. You can try this implementation also:

```
    public class ThreeStacksWithOneArray {

    //This is the stack node class
    class StackNode {
        //This is the value of the node
        int value;
        //This is showing the previous node
        int prev;
        //This is the constructor of the class
        StackNode(int value, int prev) {
            this.value = value;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }

    //This keeps the stack nodes
    private StackNode[] stackNodes = null;
    private static int CAPACITY = 10;
    //This keeps the top of free list
    private int freeListTop = 0;
    //This is the variable for the size
    private int size = 0;
    //These are the pointers to the three stacks
    private int[] stackPointers = { -1, -1, -1 };

    //This is the constructor of the main class
    ThreeStacksWithOneArray() {
        //Initialize the stack nodes
        stackNodes = new StackNode[CAPACITY];
        //initialize the free list
        initFreeList();
    }

    //Initialize the free list
    private void initFreeList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++) {
            //The value of each node is 0 and it points to the next node
            stackNodes[i] = new StackNode(0, i + 1);
        }
    }

    //This is the push procedure
    public void push(int stackNum, int value) throws Exception {
        //Print the push information
        System.out.println("Push to stack "+stackNum+" value "+value);
        int freeIndex;
        int currentStackTop = stackPointers[stackNum - 1];
        //Find the free node
        freeIndex = getFreeNodeIndex();
        //Make a new node in the free index
        StackNode n = stackNodes[freeIndex];
        //Setting the previous node
        n.prev = currentStackTop;
        //Setting the value
        n.value = value;
        stackPointers[stackNum - 1] = freeIndex;
    }

    //This is the pop method
    public StackNode pop(int stackNum) throws Exception {
        //From which stack you want to pop. -1, since it starts from 0
        int currentStackTop = stackPointers[stackNum - 1];
        //This checks for stack underflow
        if (currentStackTop == -1) {
            throw new Exception("UNDERFLOW");
        }
        //Get the node as a temp node
        StackNode temp = stackNodes[currentStackTop];
        //Remove the node from stack
        stackPointers[stackNum - 1] = temp.prev;
        //Put this node as free node
        freeStackNode(currentStackTop);
        //Print the pop information
        System.out.println("Pop from stack "+stackNum+" value: "+temp.value);
        //Return the value
        return temp;
    }

    //Get a free node index
    private int getFreeNodeIndex() throws Exception {
        int temp = freeListTop;
        //Overflow
        if (size >= CAPACITY)
            throw new Exception("OVERFLOW");
        freeListTop = stackNodes[temp].prev;
        size++;
        //return the free node index
        return temp;
    }

    //Make one index free after a pop
    private void freeStackNode(int index) {
        stackNodes[index].prev = freeListTop;
        //Put the index in free list
        freeListTop = index;
        //Decrease the size by one
        size--;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Test Driver
        ThreeStacksWithOneArray mulStack = new ThreeStacksWithOneArray();
        try {
            //Adding to those three stacks
            mulStack.push(1, 11);
            mulStack.push(1, 12);
            mulStack.push(1, 13);
            mulStack.push(1, 14);
            mulStack.push(2, 21);
            mulStack.push(2, 22);
            mulStack.push(3, 31);
            mulStack.push(3, 32);
            //Popping from those three stacks
            mulStack.pop(1);
            mulStack.pop(2);
            mulStack.pop(3);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, visit this: https://github.com/m-vahidalizadeh/foundations/blob/master/src/data_structures/ThreeStacksWithOneArray.java. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I like your implementation since it could simulate any number of stacks from one array. Vote up. My confusion is, you mentioned "You can start one of the stacks from one end of the array. You can start the other stack from the other end of the array. You can put the third stack in the middle. When, one of the side stacks need space, you need to shift the middle stack", but in your implementation, I do not see you start one stack from one end, start the other stack from the other end and start the 3rd one in the middle?

Comment: (cont'd) did I mis-read anything? Please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Yes, that is the easiest visualization possible for the people who try to understand this problem. But, the implementation that we have here is by help of free list. However, I am going to edit the response in order to omit any misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, looking forward to your update. How did freelist impacts? I think as long as you are using existing array space for  freelist, it is fine, correct (I mean not in conflict with the problem itself)?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, read your updated implementation, not sure if there is one issue in your code, in your code your return `StackNode temp` from method `pop`, the reference of the node just popped (and pointed by `temp`) is used by both free list logic and also `temp` is returned to the caller/client who calls `pop`, and the caller/client may think it owns `temp` object, and may overwrite `temp` object. It seems there will be conflict when both free list and client want to use `temp` object?

Comment: Dear Lin Ma, I updated the code. I hope this helps. Please let me know if the code still needs to be commented more.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad for the update, just to confirm my understanding is correct, the question is about using **array** to implement stacks, in your implementation, the array means **array** of `stackNodes ` (other than **array of integers**), correct?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I am using array of custom objects, I have this implementation, since it is very flexible.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, vote up for your reply and not sure there is another issue in your code, in your `pop` method, you returned `temp`, which is a reference to `StackNode`, when the client (caller of method `pop`) get the reference to `StackNode`, it may manipulate value field of the object. At the same time, reference to `StackNode` also linked to free list, and next time when you call `push`, this `StackNode` will be reused to store new value. Then there becomes an issue, the client who get the reference of `StackNode` may experience `value` field change.

Comment: (cont'd) if I read your code wrong, please feel free to correct me.